# Safe to Delete C:\ATI?

Tags: windows

Is it safe to delete the C:\ATI folder?
It keeps adding up every time there's a new version.
I was wondering if it's safe to delete all of them once the installation is complete?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can **safely delete** it. When you install ATI drivers it first extracts the installer to C:\ATI\Support\ and then installs it. Every version of ATI driver makes a folder in C:\ATI\Support. These are only installers(in your case 3 different versions). You can even re-install the drivers from here.

Comment: They never heard of %temp%. Hardware manufacturers (especially cameras!) are really not good at writing programs.